# How to send the SQL query results to a jsp page?

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I have a database with the fields id(number), name(string), address(string).

I wrote a java program EmployeeDAO to execute the query. I'm storing it in a ResultSet object `rs`. I need to display this result set as a table in a JSP page. How do I send this `rs` to the JSP page?

```
public class EmployeeDAO 
{
    public _____ list() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:employee_dsn";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from emp_table");
        }
            catch (Exception e)
        {   
             System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all create Java model class Employee with the same fields as the columns are in the emp_table. For example:

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private String lastName;
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

Then in your method _list() iterate over the result set like this:

```
public List<Employee> _ list() throws Exception {
     Connection con = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();
     try
       {
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
         String url = "jdbc:odbc:employee_dsn";
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from emp_table");
         while (rs.next()) {
           Employee emp = new Employee();
          emp.setName(rs.getString("emp_name"));
          emp.setLastName(rs.getString("emp_last_name"));
          result.add(emp);
         }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {       
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (null != rs) {
              try { rs.close()} catch(Exception ex) {};
            }
            if (null != con) {
              try { con.close()} catch(Exception ex) {};
            }
        }
return result;
  }
```

In your JSP you may iterate over the collection like this:

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="emp" items="${empDao._list}">
    <tr>
      <td>${emp.name}</td>
      <td>${emp.lastName}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elegant solution would be to map your resultset to a list of objects. Take a look at springs [RowMapper](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) to get an idea of how to handle this.

In your jsp you can than use a `<c:forEach/>` loop to write out this list.